# Add fade effect change of background using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, background, fade

I have the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var bgCounter = 0,
        backgrounds = [
           "images/2.png",
           "images/1.png",
           "images/3.png"
        ];

    function changeBackground()
    {
        bgCounter = (bgCounter+1) % backgrounds.length;
        $('#page').css('background', '#000 url('+backgrounds[bgCounter]+') no-repeat');
        setTimeout(changeBackground,100000);
    }

    changeBackground();
    });
```

I need to add fade in/out effect, between background changes. Any guidance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add this:

`$('#page').fadeIn()`

before

`$('#page').css('background', '#000 url('+backgrounds[bgCounter]+') no-repeat');`

And this:

`$('#page').fadeOut()`

after it..

Answer (score 2):

Try this one:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
 var bgCounter = 0,
    backgrounds = [
       "images/2.png",
       "images/1.png",
       "images/3.png"
    ];

 function changeBackground()
 {
    bgCounter = (bgCounter+1) % backgrounds.length;
      $('#page').animate({
     opacity: 0
    }, 0).css({
          'background-image': 'url('+backgrounds[bgCounter]+')'
     }).animate({opacity: 1}, 1000);

 setTimeout(changeBackground,10000);
 }

 changeBackground();
 });
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/nq7uE/8/

Comment: Thanks m8, it works but the Karim AG example works better for me